# How Can I only save filled in entry widgets without saving the empty entry widget in atext file using Tkinter app?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, truss

I am  creating a simple app for truss analysis and I have to collect and save some data in a text file.According to my code I can only solve for 6 nodes maximum (6 entry boxes).However when I dont fill in all the boxes it also saves the empty boxes as empty string.For example if i put coordinates for 3 nodes i.e the first 3 boxes.I am getting the following;

```
nodes = {'1': ['0', '0'], '2': ['1', '1'], '3': ['2', '2'], '': ['', '']}
```

How can I program my save button to only save the filled in data from user and nothing more?

My code is below;

```
from tkinter import*
root = Tk()
root.geometry("480x480")
root.title ("TRUSS 2D")
# creating coordinates input

myLabel = Label(root,text = "Coordinates")
myLabel.grid (row = 0,column = 0)
myLabel9 = Label(root,text = "Node")
myLabel9.grid (row = 1,column = 0, columnspan = 1 )
e_1 = Entry(root,width=5,borderwidth=5)
e_1.grid(row = 2,column = 0)
e_2 = Entry(root,width=5,borderwidth=5)
e_2.grid(row = 3,column = 0)
e_3 = Entry(root,width=5,borderwidth=5)
e_3.grid(row = 4,column = 0)
e_4 = Entry(root,width=5,borderwidth=5)
e_4.grid(row = 5,column = 0)
e_5 = Entry(root,width=5,borderwidth=5)
e_5.grid(row = 6,column = 0)
e_6 = Entry(root,width=5,borderwidth=5)
e_6.grid(row = 7,column = 0)
myLabel_x0 = Label(root,text = "x0")
myLabel_x0.grid (row = 2,column = 1)
e_x0 = Entry(root,width=5,borderwidth=5)
e_x0.grid(row = 2,column = 2)
myLabel_y0 = Label(root,text = "y0")
myLabel_y0.grid (row = 2,column = 3)
e_y0 = Entry(root,width=5,borderwidth=5)
e_y0.grid(row = 2,column = 4)
myLabel_x1 = Label(root,text = "x1")
myLabel_x1.grid (row = 3,column = 1)
e_x1 = Entry(root,width=5,borderwidth=5)
e_x1.grid(row = 3,column = 2)
myLabel_y1 = Label(root,text = "y1")
myLabel_y1.grid (row = 3,column = 3)
e_y1 = Entry(root,width=5,borderwidth=5)
e_y1.grid(row = 3,column = 4)
myLabel_x2 = Label(root,text = "x2")
myLabel_x2.grid (row = 4,column = 1)
e_x2 = Entry(root,width=5,borderwidth=5)
e_x2.grid(row = 4,column = 2)
myLabel_y2 = Label(root,text = "y2")
myLabel_y2.grid (row = 4,column = 3)
e_y2 = Entry(root,width=5,borderwidth=5)
e_y2.grid(row = 4,column = 4)
myLabel_x3 = Label(root,text = "x3")
myLabel_x3.grid (row = 5,column = 1)
e_x3 = Entry(root,width=5,borderwidth=5)
e_x3.grid(row = 5,column = 2)
myLabel_y3 = Label(root,text = "y3")
myLabel_y3.grid (row = 5,column = 3)
e_y3 = Entry(root,width=5,borderwidth=5)
e_y3.grid(row = 5,column = 4)
myLabel_x4 = Label(root,text = "x4")
myLabel_x4.grid (row = 6,column = 1)
e_x4 = Entry(root,width=5,borderwidth=5)
e_x4.grid(row = 6,column = 2)
myLabel_y4 = Label(root,text = "y4")
myLabel_y4.grid (row = 6,column = 3)
e_y4 = Entry(root,width=5,borderwidth=5)
e_y4.grid(row = 6,column = 4)
myLabel_x5 = Label(root,text = "x5")
myLabel_x5.grid (row = 7,column = 1)
e_x5 = Entry(root,width=5,borderwidth=5)
e_x5.grid(row = 7,column = 2)
myLabel_y5 = Label(root,text = "y5")
myLabel_y5.grid (row =7 ,column = 3)
e_y5 = Entry(root,width=5,borderwidth=5)
e_y5.grid(row = 7,column = 4) 
# add data to text file
def save():
    node_1 = e_1.get()
    node_2 =e_2.get()
    node_3 =e_3.get()
    node_4 =e_4.get()
    node_5 =e_5.get()
    node_6 =e_6.get()
    x0 = e_x0.get()
    y0 = e_y0.get()
    x1 = e_x1.get()
    y1 = e_y1.get()
    x2 = e_x2.get()
    y2 = e_y2.get()
    x3 = e_x3.get()
    y3 = e_y3.get()
    x4 = e_x4.get()
    y4 = e_y4.get()
    x5 = e_x5.get()
    y5 = e_y5.get()

    line = str({node_1:[x0,y0],node_2:[x1,y1],node_3:[x2,y2],node_4:[x3,y3],node_5:[x4,y4],node_6:[x5,y5]})
    name_string = line.strip('\"')
    print("nodes = " + line,name_string,file = open("input.txt","a"))

    file.close()
btn=Button(root, text="save", command = save).grid(row=8,column = 4)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use a for loop to create the input rows and use a list to store the entry boxes.  Then it is easier to create the output dict for saving:

```
   rows = []  # how the input entry boxes
    for i in range(6):
        # name
        entry = Entry(root, width=5, bd=5)
        entry.grid(row=2+i, column=0)
        # Node
        myLabel1 = Label(root, text=f'Node')
        myLabel1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        # x
        myLabel2 = Label(root, text=f'x{i}')
        myLabel2.grid(row=2+i, column=1)
        entry_x = Entry(root, width=5, bd=5)
        entry_x.grid(row=2+i, column=2)
        # y
        myLabel3 = Label(root, text=f'y{i}')
        myLabel3.grid(row=2+i, column=3)
        entry_y = Entry(root, width=5, bd=5)
        entry_y.grid(row=2+i, column=4)
        # save current input row
        rows.append((entry, entry_x, entry_y))

    # add data to text file
    def save():
        nodes = {int(name.get()):[int(ex.get()), int(ey.get())] for name,ex,ey in rows if name.get() and ex.get() and ey.get()}
        if nodes:
            with open('input.txt', 'a') as f:
                print('nodes =', nodes, file=f)
    myButton_save = Button(root, text="save",padx = 10,pady = 10, command=save)
    myButton_save.grid(row=8, column=4)
    # delete data from window
    def clear():
        with open("input.txt", "r+") as f:
            d = f.readlines()
            f.seek(0)
            for i in d:
                if i != "nodes":
                    f.write(i)
            f.truncate()
    myButton_clear = Button(root, text="clear",padx = 10,pady = 10, command=clear)
    myButton_clear.grid(row=8, column=5)
    def close():
         for name,ex,ey in rows:
             name.destroy()
             ex.destroy()
             ey.destroy()
        lbl = myLabel1,myLabel2,myLabel3
        for lbl in rows:
            lbl.destroy()
            lbl.destroy()
            lbl.destroy()
        myButton_save.destroy()
        myButton_clear.destroy()
        myButton_close.destroy()
    myButton_close = Button(root, text="close",padx = 10,pady = 10, command=close)
    myButton_close.grid(row=8, column=6)
```

Comment: This is actually a much cleaner and readable way than my answer for placement of the widgets

Comment: @acw1668 Thank you so much for the reply.The code works perfectly fine and I have included in my rest of the code.I am trying to clear(using new button I have defined as "close") everything from the window including buttons which I can do expect for the labels.I tried introducing two variables as myLabel 1 & myLabel 2 then I tried using .destroy() to remove them as well.While I am not getting any error nothing happens to the labels they are still stuck on the window.How do you recommend me to solve this issue?Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand fully what you said without seeing the updated code.

Comment: I have updated the code above this comment thread.While I am not getting any errorI can still see the lables on the winow after everything else is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to solve this.
First

```
line = {node_1: [x0, y0], node_2: [x1, y1], node_3: [x2, y2], node_4: [x3, y3], node_5: [x4, y4], node_6: [x5, y5]}
line.pop('', None)
```

This code removes any element in the line dictionary with the key: ''. However, if your program grows, you will be creating a large line dictionary with blank elements and then removing them which may be inefficient?

A second, perhaps more efficient way is to check if the entry box is populated in the first place and insert the node into the line dictionary if it is populated: [Tkinter check if entry box is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455113/tkinter-check-if-entry-box-is-empty)

EDIT:
Thinking about it, the way you have created the entry boxes is fine if you limit yourself to a small number of trusses/nodes, if you plan to expand the program the following more iterative way of creating entry widgets may help you:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("480x480")
root.title("TRUSS 2D")
# creating coordinates input

myLabel = Label(root, text="Coordinates")
myLabel.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=4)
myLabel9 = Label(root, text="Node")
myLabel9.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=1)
# removed long list of widget creation

# array to hold widget elements
e_list = []
for i in range(0, 5):
    e_list.append([Entry(root, width=5, borderwidth=5), Label(root, text="x"), Entry(root, width=5, borderwidth=5),
                   Label(root, text="y"), Entry(root, width=5, borderwidth=5)])

row = 2
column = 0
# place elements iteratively, this all depends on the order of the e_list list
for e in e_list:
    for element in e:
        element.grid(row=row, column=column)
        column += 1
    row += 1
    column = 0



# add data to text file
def save():
    lines = dict()

    for e in e_list:
        # check to make sure the number, x and y boxes are all populated
        # The elements check depends on the order of e_list

        if e[0].index('end') != 0 and e[2].index('end') != 0 and e[4].index('end') != 0:
            if e[0].get() in lines:
                print('Multiple nodes with the same number!')
            else:
                # The elements to assign depends on the order of e_list
                lines[e[0].get()] = [e[2].get(), e[4].get()]
    print(lines)
    # need to format the dictionary and save etc.

btn = Button(root, text="save", command=save).grid(row=8, column=4)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: Results from the EDIT code. Note, node 2 x and y boxes aren't populated and don't show up in the terminal output]

Comment: Thank you for solving the issue,how can I remove the single quotation marks on the output?I just want them to be saved as integers

Comment: It's just a matter of converting the entry box strings to integers `lines[int(e[0].get())] = [int(e[2].get()), int(e[4].get())]`